# Simplifying a SQL query in an Apex application

Tags: sql, database, oracle-apex

I have an Apex application, that contains several drop down bars that allow users to select various values to query the attached database with. Basically the query is becoming huge due to the conditions placed within it. The conditions are such that it checks each value within all the dropdowns or whether they're null etc. The question I have is there anyway of simplifying the query so that i dont have to write every possible combination of data being input. Like this field is null this one isnt, now this one is etc.

An example of how the conditions look -

```
OR
(plant_type.plant_type = :P1_PLANT_TYPE AND plant.plant_name = :P1_PLANT_NAME AND :P3_SOIL IS NULL AND :P3_SUNLIGHT IS NULL)
OR 
(plant_type.plant_type = :P1_PLANT_TYPE AND :P1_PLANT_NAME IS NULL AND :P3_SOIL IS NULL AND :P3_SUNLIGHT IS NULL) 
OR
(sunlight_conditions.condition_details = :P3_SUNLIGHT AND :P3_SOIL IS NULL AND plant_type.plant_type = :P1_PLANT_TYPE AND plant.plant_name = :P1_PLANT_NAME)
OR
(soil_conditions.soil_condition = :P3_SOIL AND :P3_SUNLIGHT IS NULL AND plant_type.plant_type = :P1_PLANT_TYPE AND plant.plant_name = :P1_PLANT_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way would be to include every query condition only once, like this:

```
(plant_type.plant_type = :P1_PLANT_TYPE or :P1_PLANT_TYPE IS NULL)
and
(plant.plant_name = :P1_PLANT_NAME or :P1_PLANT_NAME IS NULL)
and
(sunlight_conditions.condition_details = :P3_SUNLIGHT or :P3_SUNLIGHT IS NULL)
and
(soil_conditions.soil_condition = :P3_SOIL or :P3_SOIL IS NULL)
```

Of course, it depends if you want an OR condition between them or and AND condition. Usually it's AND and so my answer will help you.

Comment: haha Damn. Thanks Alen! I've been puzzling on it for a while and hadn't actually considered this it makes everything a lot easier. I cant believe i didn't think to try this before asking, sorry. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lot of your combinations are "allowing" some items to be null.

One way to do that is have all the combinations but use COALESCE fall over to a true condition.  For example you can change all the items you have listed there too the following

```
 plant_type.plant_type = COALESCE(:P1_PLANT_TYPE,plant_type.plant_type) AND 
 plant.plant_name = COALESCE(:P1_PLANT_NAME, plant.plant_name) AND
 soil_conditions.soil_condition = COALESCE(:P3_SOIL,soil_conditions.soil_condition) AND
 sunlight_conditions.condition_details = COALESCE(:P3_SUNLIGHT,sunlight_conditions.condition_details)
```

---

If could be the case that the above does not meet your logic rules.  In that case you might have to create a conditions table which you join to.  That table could describe the logic of which items "go with" which others.

I'd have to see all your business rules to figure out if it is needed and how that would be created, but that is the best way when the wheres get out of control.  It is a relational database after all.. .make a relation to solve it!